# Counter Decrements in a wrong way

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, local-storage

I have some data stored in localStorage, I want to output these data dynamically (When "before"And "After" arrows are clicked). I redirect the page to itself & make the day's name be displayed when document is ready.

When I click Next, the days are incremented correctly, but when I click before, the day is not decremented correctly, I tried to handle the case of (if counter =-1, counter= maxcounter) but it didn't work... 
This is what I tried:

Javascript:

```
 function GetCurrentDay() {
     if (localStorage["CurrentDay"] == null || localStorage["CurrentDay"] == 'NaN' || localStorage["CurrentDay"]=="undefined") {
         localStorage["Counter"]= 0;
         i = localStorage["Counter"];
         localStorage["CurrentDay"] = localStorage["Day" + i];
    }
    return localStorage["CurrentDay"];
}
function GoToNextDay() {
    var d = GetCurrentDay();
    i = localStorage["Counter"];
    i = i*1 + 1;
    localStorage["Counter"] = i;
    if(i!= localStorage["SchoolDays"]+1){
        localStorage["CurrentDay"] = localStorage["Day" + i];
    }else{
        localStorage["CurrentDay"] = localStorage["Day" + 0];    
    }
    return true;
}
function GoToPrevDay() {
    var d = GetCurrentDay();
    i = localStorage["Counter"];
    i = i*1 - 1;
    localStorage["Counter"]=i;
    if(i>0){  
        localStorage["CurrentDay"] = localStorage["Day" + i];
    }else{
        i=localStorage["SchoolDays"];
        localStorage["Counter"]=i; 
        localStorage["CurrentDay"] = localStorage["Day" + i];    
    }
    return true;
}
```

Do you have any ideas on how can I fix it?

Comment: You love assignments too much, to re-re-assign everything

Comment: You've commented `CurrentDay` to replace it with `CurrentDate`. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: Don't store everything in the localStorage. Especially when working on the data, first load, then change, and at last store it - not everything at once.

Comment: @Bergi I have to store them coz I re-use them later. Do you have a better method?

Comment: Use variables. Load the values from localStorage when loading the page, and store them back when leaving (or after a update). Use separate functions for those actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand why you need local storage to display and increment a day. Without more information regarding what behaviour you expect it's difficult to give a fully informed answer. First of all, as Bergi suggested in the comments, you're abusing local storage.

For example, instead of:

```
function GetCurrentDay() {
     if (localStorage["CurrentDay"] == null || localStorage["CurrentDay"] == 'NaN' || localStorage["CurrentDay"]=="undefined") {
         localStorage["Counter"]= 0;
         i = localStorage["Counter"];
         localStorage["CurrentDay"] = localStorage["Day" + i];
    }
    return localStorage["CurrentDay"];
}
```

you could do:

```
function GetCurrentDay() {
    var currentDay = localStorage.CurrentDay;
    if (!currentDay) {
        var counter = 0;
        currentDay = localStorage["Day" + counter];
    }
    localStorage.Counter = counter;
    localStorage.CurrentDay = currentDay;

    return currentDay;
}
```

The above approach is much better because you only access localStorage when you need to get or set certain values. Everything in between happens on local variables which is going to be much faster. Also, where possible you should use dot notation to access javascript objects. It's just a lot more readable.

Now, back to the fundamental question. Are you sure you need localStorage at all? It sounds like you're reloading the page and using localStorage to keep track of certain values. It would be much much easier for you and for your visitors if you avoided this and updated this day field dynamically. For example, say you have an html structure like this somewhere in your page:

```
<div id="day">0</div>
<span id="next">Next</span>
<span id="previous">Previous</span>
```

You could listen to click events and update it accordingly.

```
var day = 0,
    dayEl = document.getElementById('day');

document.getElementById('next').onclick = function() {
    dayEl.firstChild.nodeValue = ++day;
}

document.getElementById('previous').onclick = function() {
    dayEl.firstChild.nodeValue = --day;
}
```

No need for localStorage and no page reloads. The above example is highly simplified but I hope it gets the point across and helps you reconsider your approach.